# Notebook application which uses HTML as its native file format

Tags: laptop, editing, html, wysiwyg, outline

Does anyone know of a wysiwyg application for taking notes, preferably in a tree structure, which loads from and saves to HTML directly?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/):

> TiddlyWiki is a single html file which
>   has all the characteristics of a wiki
>   - including all of the content, the functionality (including editing,
>   saving, tagging and searching) and the
>   style sheet. Because it's a single
>   file, it's very portable - you can
>   email it, put it on a web server or
>   share it via a USB stick.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Google Docs](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/tour1.html) might suit you, it can be [used offline if needed](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/03/offline-google-docs.html).

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for an editor to embed into your Web page, or to use as a desktop tool?

If it's the latter, I'd suggest picking the tool you are most comfortable with. I'm a big fan of TiddlyWiki, but you may wish to have something that runs as a native app instead. Almost all the current note taking and mind mapping programs out there have an HTML export option (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_notetaking_software). And if all you need is a basic bullet list, there are plenty of good HTML editors like Amaya, CoffeeCup and BlueFish.

On the other hand, if what you are after is a way to take notes directly on a web page or web application, the editor component I'd recommend is TinyMCE. There was a recent review of the top 25 editors on Smashing Magazine, check it out for a good overview.